# False positive, Review Queue indicator

Tags: bug

Multiple times daily, I check in at Hardware Recommendations, and see there's an indicator telling me something is in the Review Queue for me.

[image: Screenshot fragment of the Review Queue indicator]

Yet, when I click on it, there's nothing there.

It was suggested, before I passed 1,000 quatloos, that several of my own items were in the queue, and the red dot was indicating there were items to review, but when I looked, I was not shown your own posts. Well, now I've cleared the Review Queue, and the issue persists.

Where's the best place to report this bug?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that several of your own items are in the queue. The red dot is saying there are items to review, but when you go to look you are not being shown your own posts.

I don't know if that is intended behavior or not, but that's my current theory. I'm basing that on having opening two queues and your posts were the first item that popped up in each queue.

Comment: However, when I checked this morning, there's no Review Queue indicator, even though those pending edits are still there. This makes me disinclined to believe that's the explanation.

Comment: And, now that I have cleared all of my reviews in the queue, the issue persists.